# Yii cgridview filter dropdown issue width on IE8

Tags: yii, internet-explorer-8, cgridview

The issue:

Some of the items in the dropdown filter require more than the specified width in order to display fully and this only happens on IE8. I am using Yii 1.1.13

[image]

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, i just added next code:

```
    .grid-view .filters select:focus
         {
             width: auto;
             position: relative;
         }
```

into **gridview/styles.css** file